# NSMutableArray.count is always zero but objects are there and can be used

Tags: methods, count, nsmutablearray, zero

I'm using a method to populate an array. Before I return the array I can count the number of objects with friendsArray.count and I get 3.
In the method where I use the array I call it with the following code.

```
     userHomeDetails   *friendsInstance =[[userHomeDetails alloc] init];
     self.friendsImageInstance = [friendsInstance getFriendsImage:1];
     NSLog(@"size of array %d", friendsImageInstance.count);
```

userHomeDetails is an NSObject where I keep the method to call the database.
getfriendsImage is the method where I call the database and before returning the array I can see I have a count of 3.
friendsImageInstance is an NSMutableArray declared, allocated and initialized, this is the array I want to count.

when I check the count for friendsImageInstance.count it returns 0. but It has data and I can use it and populate my table no issues.

any clues?

Comment: Is `userHomeDetails` subclassed from `NSMutableArray`?

Answer (score 0):

Got it. it was very simple I didn't synthesize friendsImageInstance. done and all working. Thanks  iNailuY  for taking a look at my problem, appreciate it.